# Spring Boot Google Oauth2 all requests return a 401 Unauthorized

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I have a very simple Spring Boot app where I want *all* pages to be authenticated thtough Google Oauth2. I followed the [Spring Oauth2 tuotrial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) and looked at the [code under the /simple implementation](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2). (My application.yml file is setup for Google instead of FB)

Any request to my app returns a 401 Unauthorized response, and goes to localhost:8080/login... (The Spring security auto generated login page, which is set as the Redirect URI in Google developer console)

I have looked at all the other questions that try to answer this issue, but none have been of help.

My Application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@RestController
public class ControlApplication  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ControlApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/", false);
    }

}
```

And my application.yml:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: [MyClientID]
      clientSecret: [MyClientSecret]
      accessTokenUri: https://accounts.google.com/o/auth2/token
      userAuthorizationUri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?hd=xyz.com
      redirectUri: http://localhost:8080
      clientAuthenticationScheme: form
      tokenName: oauth_token
      authenticationScheme: query
      scope:
        - email
        - profile
    resource:
      userInfoUri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo
      preferTokenInfo: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. (Finally!) The issue appears to be wrong config for acessTokenUri in calling the Google Auth API. Working config:

```
  accessTokenUri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
  userAuthorizationUri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?hd=xyz.com
  clientAuthenticationScheme: form
  scope:
    - openid
    - email
    - profile
resource:
  userInfoUri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo
  preferTokenInfo: true
```